# How can I hide a node flag using twig

Tags: theming, flags

I want to hide the flag on a node if a boolean field is unchecked.

My Code in node.html.twig

```
{% if node.field_registration_status.value == 0 %}

<div class="registration-closed">

    {{ content|without('content.flag_class_registration') }}

  </div>

{% endif %}

{% if node.field_registration_status.value == 1 %}

   <div class="registration-open">

     {{ content }}

   </div>

{% endif %}
```

My CSS classes print as expected when the field is checked or unchecked. However, the Flag is not being removed from the output.

Answer (score 2):

The `without()` filter's argument should be just the name of the key itself, which in this case is `flag_class_registration` without the `content.`. Consider - the filter only receives the expression that comes before it, so it's already inside the content array.

```
   {{ content|without('flag_class_registration') }}
```